# Turn on symfony2 assetic only in dev env

Tags: symfony, assetic, uglifyjs, uglifycss

Can I use assetic if I can't install anything on prod env? Is it possible to use assetic with uglifyjs and uglifycss only on dev env and use "uglified" files in prod env?

Answer (score 0):

We have had similar issues - where some features are not deployed onto production servers.  The work round we use is to deploy the prod environment to a build server - then once all the assets have been created then to rsync the symfony and web directory (containing the generated assets) to the production server.

It is not ideal - but it does work for us.

We also have implemented some additional filters in twig to get round some of the short comings.

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is the default behavior :)

If you want to deploy your code just call `app/console assetic:dump --no-debug` and assetic will compile the css/js/image files for you and save it to the `web` directory.